# an I use the same auto renew product ids for both mac and ios

Tags: ios, macos, in-app-purchase, subscriptions, auto-renewing

I have an ios app that I am offering non consumable product auto renewing subscriptions (cloud space) and am now getting ready to do a Mac version for and would like to use the same product id's for sale for both platforms so that the entitlements are accessible on either platform.  Is that possible? I looked in the Apple documentation and it is either not there or I did not see it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think apple provided proper document on this.

1)Make sure that In-App Purchase product IDs on the app aren't the same product IDs on any apps in the recipient's account, follow the below link.

[Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)

Hope this will help you...

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry for the delayed reply.